# Как передать jquery элемент, или его аттрибуты в другой метод?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите как можно передать jquery элемент, или его аттрибуты в другой метод?
И какие еще есть другие варианты? как вы это делаете?

И как правильно реализовать если у меня на странице надо прослушивать 10 ссылок (кликов)?

```
<button class="js_btn" data-id="23"></button>
var myApp = {
    setListeners: function() {
        $('.js_btn').on('click', $.proxy(this.myMethod, this));
    },
    myMethod: function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(id);
    }
}

myApp.setListeners();
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: delegate или on или live (в зависимости от версии и надобностей)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1й вопрос - `$.proxy(this.myMethod)` без второго параметра

2й вопрос - как сказал [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)  - on

```
var myApp = {
    setListeners: function() {
        $('#parent').on('click', '.js_btn',$.proxy(this.myMethod));
    },
    myMethod: function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(id);
    }
};

myApp.setListeners();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/UBfNf/